# how to grouped the chart.js bar chart with multiple values and multiple labels

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

here is the response and here i m able to show user_name in labels but at the time of datasets in data and label when i m itetrating all data is showing in one user i want to show product_code in datasets label and total_amount in data in datasets but unable to do

```
top10Earners(dataSets, labels) {
        const ctx4: ChartItem = document.getElementById('top-10-earners-chart') as ChartItem;
        if (isDefined(this.chart4)) {
            this.chart4.destroy()
        }
        this.chart4 = new Chart(ctx4, {
                    type: 'bar',
                    data: {
                        labels: labels,
                        // ['Jack', 'Mike', 'Jenny', 'Melinda', 'Mark', 'Blenda', 'Marcus', 'Mark', 'Blenda', 'Marcus'],
                        datasets: dataSets
                    }
                }

                [{
                    product_code: ['CIC', 'COC']
                    total_amount: [9, 1.5]
                    user_name: "sharu Admin"
                } {
                    product_code: ['CIC']
                    total_amount: [3]
                    user_name: "Dhivya App"
                } {
                    product_code: ['CIC']
                    total_amount: [2]
                    user_name: "Rossy Agentapp"
                }]
```

here is the image I want to show data

[image]